# Projections and open maps

Tags: general-topology

I have the projection $\pi_x : X \times Y \to X$ where $\pi_x$ is defined as: $\pi_x(x,y) = x$. How can I show this is an open map? I know that a map $f: X \to Y$ is an open map if whenever $U$ is open in $X$, $f(U)$ is open in $Y$. However, the exercise doesn't specify a topology so how can I show something is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not specified, $X\times Y$ has the [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).

Answer (score 0):

We will refer to $\pi_x$ as just $\pi$. Since every open set in $X \times Y$ is a union of sets of the form $U \times V$  with $U$ open in $X$, $V$ open in Y, and since direct images of unions are the union of the images, we only need to check that $\pi(U \times V)$ is open in $X$. But this set, namely $\{pi(u,v) \mid u \in U, \;v \in V\}$, is just $U$ again. I assumed $V$ is nonempty if $U$ is, so that $U \times V$ is nonempty. This same method works for $\pi_y$ as well.